# Getting FerrersDiagram to work

Tags: plotting, graphics, combinatorics

I am trying to generate FerrersDiagram (see http://reference.wolfram.com/language/Combinatorica/ref/FerrersDiagram.html), any clues to getting it to work? I get error message for the following:

```
<< Combinatorica`

FerrersDiagram[10]

(* combinatorica Graph and Permutations functionality has been superseded 
by preloaded functionality. The package now being loaded may conflict 
with this. Please see the Compatibility Guide for details.*)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Argument should be a partition:

FerrersDiagram[{1, 1, 2, 2, 4}]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

With respect to my question, I was after the partitioning of 10  between 2 and 4 integers, so "ulvi" ans. helped.

```
Show[FerrersDiagram[IntegerPartitions[10, {2, 4}]], Frame -> True, 
     FrameLabel -> {Style["N", Large, Bold], 
       Style["Level", Large, Bold]}, RotateLabel -> True, 
     LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Large]]
```

[image]